# Find the current location using CLGeocoder Reverse Geocoding

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

I want to find the  current location of user based on latitude and longitude. Prevoiusly I have done it using MKReverseGeocoder but as it is depracated in ios5 ,I going with CLGeocoder.But unable to get the current location .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        [locationManager setDelegate:self];
        [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
        [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    locationLabelOne=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;


    locationLabelTwo=newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];


    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);
        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
           NSString *get = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
                                 placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
                                 placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea,
                                 placemark.country];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    } ];
    NSLog(@"%@",placemark);
}
```

When I NSLog placemark it is returning null.Where I m going wrong?

Comment: Try logging the currentLocation after `CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;` to check if the value is getting set. Also you can debug each line to see if the values are set properly.

Comment: `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` is deprecated  iOS 6.0 you should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` instead.

Comment: Yes When I log currentlocation I get this :<+37.78583400,-122.40641700> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 3/15/13, 12:33:00 PM India Standard Time

Comment: @rohan-patel can u please tell me how can I pass latitude and longitude now in this :?

Comment: Ya. I am trying to figure out. But first could you tell me how you are getting speed `(speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00)` in NSlog?

Comment: I just got it .I donno how.

Comment: Try `NSLog NSString *get` and tell me what happens.

Comment: It is returning null.

Comment: NSLog **`placemarks`**

Comment: Both placemarks and get are returning null

Comment: NSLog `newLocation.coordinate.latitude/longitude` above this line `locationLabelOne=newLocation.coordinate.latitude;`issue is there only now.

Comment: 37.7 and 122.4 refers to Apple HQ in San Francisco I believe. Also CLGeocoder does not work very well in India. Being in Bangalore, I was able to get reverse geocoded location "Bangalore" only once in about 1000 tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible issues:

1)  `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` is deprecated iOS 6.0 you should use `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` instead.

```
 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
     currentLocation=[locations lastObject];
     // rest code will be same
 }
```

2) Also  `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` sounds fishy. IMO you should not use that in `CLLocationManagerDelegate`method.

**P.S.**

i) For more details in Forward/Reverse geocoding you can look into Apple's sample code [**GeocoderDemo**](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097)

ii) If you use Google API for Reverse Geocoding it will have all data available it has been for years but `CLGeocoder` will not have complete data like street name, pin code for countries like India. What happens is, when you do Reverse Geocoding requests, you pass co ordinates to Core Location which connects to web service in background(which developer won't come to know) and returns a user-readable address. So it may be possible this web service may not be able to return data as accurate as GOOGLE API.

Comment: Hey I found this error now :Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 8.)"
What shall I do ?

Comment: Did you try that on device? Just try to get `placemark.country` and see what happens.

Comment: Hey I have placed another code and it seems to work.I m using this CLGeocoder to show directions from current location to destination address and I m using GOogle API for that.I want to know whether CLGeocoder always returns Street,City,State,Zip in all the cases.Because I need to use all of them to show directions...Can u please tell me this point..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,  then with some experimentation I solved my problem…

Make sure:
-90 < latitude < 90
-180 < longitude < 180

It doesn't seem to perform a basic mod function.  Hope that helps...